# How to dynamically cast something that does not name a type

Tags: c++

I'm not very strong with C++, so please bear with me :-)

I'm trying to debug someone else's code.  I believe the code worked in gcc4 but is croaking in gcc6.  (Just offerred as a clue, I'm not 100% on that)

Here's an excerpt of the code...

```
  if (IsCacheManagementRequest()) {
    auto vicQAlloc = GetTransaction<tVicQAllocConst>(k_VicQAlloc);
    return log2(vicQAlloc->GetAllocate());
  } else if (IsL3Victim()) {
    auto vicQAlloc = GetSourceOfL3Victim()->GetTransaction<tVicQAllocConst> (k_VicQAlloc);    
    return log2(vicQAlloc->GetAllocate());
  } else if (IsTraceCaptureRequest()) {
etc...
```

This is the error I'm getting (the error message points to the 3rd line in the excerpt, the "log2(...)")...

```
 error: call of overloaded 'log2(nL3s::cVicQAlloc::tAllocate)' is ambiguous
```

From what I've read, the vicQAlloc->GetAllocate() is not returning a specific type (at least not specific enough) and/or the log2 function is not specifying the type of data it wants. There's ambiguity and I get this error.

I read that if you cast the thing being returned, this might fix the problem. 
 So I tried dynamic casting, but it failed...

```
if (IsCacheManagementRequest()) {
    auto vicQAlloc = GetTransaction<tVicQAllocConst>(k_VicQAlloc);
    return log2(dynamic_cast<vicQAlloc->GetAllocate()>);
} else if (IsL3Victim()) {
    auto vicQAlloc = GetSourceOfL3Victim()->GetTransaction<tVicQAllocConst (k_VicQAlloc);
return log2(dynamic_cast<vicQAlloc->GetAllocate()>);
} else if (IsTraceCaptureRequest()) {
etc...
```

Error msg...

```
error: 'vicQAlloc' does not name a type                                                                                                                                                  
     return log2(dynamic_cast<vicQAlloc->GetAllocate()>);
```

I'm looking for a way to get around this without uprooting much.  If the gcc6 is picky about this where gcc4 was not, is there a way to make it behave as if was gcc4? (maybe a compile option ?).

Any ideas ?

=========================

## UPDATE

I think I found the declaration of "log2".  It looks like i's up in some sort of 3rd party pkg install in a header called "nmathcalls.h".  Here it is...

```
/* Compute base-2 logarithm of X.  */
__MATHCALL (log2,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
__END_NAMESPACE_C99
#endif
```

Mdouble ?

In the header of that file there's a description of Mdouble...

```
This file provides prototype declarations for the math functions.
Most functions are declared using the macro:

__MATHCALL (NAME,[_r], (ARGS...));

This means there is a function `NAME' returning `double' and a function
`NAMEf' returning `float'.  Each place `_Mdouble_' appears in the
prototype, that is actually `double' in the prototype for `NAME' and
`float' in the prototype for `NAMEf'.  Reentrant variant functions are
called `NAME_r' and `NAMEf_r'.
```

So is this thing just looking for a double ?

Comment: "This is the error I'm getting"  There's more to that error.  Please include _all the lines_ to that error.  The one message is several lines.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<vicQAlloc->GetAllocate()>` is not valid syntax, you're missing what type you want to cast to (and put what you want to cast in the wrong spot)

Comment: The syntax for `dynamic_cast` is `dynamic_cast<type_to_cast_to>(thing_to_cast)`.  That said, you should probably analyze the error message and determine which `log2` functions the compiler is saying the expression can use used for.

Comment: Reading the rest of the compiler output that comes immediately after that error message will be much more productive than trying to search through header files yourself.

Comment: Every function has a return type, there is no such thing as a function "not returning a specific type".  The thing you need to look up is `nL3s::cVicQAlloc::tAllocate`  , not `log2`,  to find out how that type relates to the possible types that `log2` accepts

Answer (score 1):

OK, that seems to have fixed it.  I just cast the argument as a double...

```
return log2((double) vicQAlloc->GetAllocate());
```

Thanks for the pointers everyone.  Finding the def of log2 was the key !

Comment: [log2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) is a Standard C++ function

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have already answered your own question with a few tips from comments; here it is in short:

This is the line of code in question:

> ```
> return log2(vicQAlloc->GetAllocate());
> ```

This is part of the compiler error:

> ```
> error: call of overloaded 'log2(nL3s::cVicQAlloc::tAllocate)' is ambiguous
> ```

You have determined that you are getting ambiguity so that's a given.

The question then becomes: how to resolve the ambiguity?

Then you discovered the signature - definition for `log2(...){...;}`

Now the question becomes what type or types does `log2()` accept or expect; and what type(s) do(es) `vicQAlloc->GetAllocate()` return(s)?

Once you know the two above, then the final question becomes: how do you either convert or cast from the return type to the parameter expected type?